# Grouped UITableView & Section Index

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

There's this piece of information in Apple's docs for `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`:

> You implement this method only for table views with a section index list — which can only be table views created in the plain style (`UITableViewStylePlain`).

(Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Does anybody know why is that? I'm making an app that has a grouped table view (`UITableViewStyleGrouped`) with an index and it works without any issues. Is the documentation wrong or am I missing something obvious?